# java.lang.NullPointerException when try click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, cucumber

**I get java.lang.NullPointerException when I try use method getClickOnHotelTab()**

The method getClickOnHotelPage is on the page SearchHotelPage. When I try use this method on SearchHotelStep I got java.lang.NullPointerException.

**This is my SearchHotelPage:**

```
public class SearchHotelPage {

public WebDriver driver;

private By clickOnHotelTab = By.xpath("//*[@id='PageNavBarSectionList']//a[@title='Hotéis']");
private By destinyClick1 = By.xpath("(//div[@role='button']/span)[3]");
private By destinyClick2 = By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Destino ou nome do hotel']");

public SearchHotelPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public WebElement getDestinyClick1() {
    return driver.findElement(destinyClick1);
}

public WebElement getDestinyClick2() {
    return driver.findElement(destinyClick2);
}

public WebElement getClickOnHotelTab() {
    return driver.findElement(clickOnHotelTab);
}
```

---

**This is my SearchHotelStep:**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class SearchHotelStep extends BasePage {

public WebDriver driver;

@When("^Choose destiny or hotel name$")
public void choose_destiny_or_hotel_name() throws Throwable {
    
    SearchHotelPage destinyClick = new SearchHotelPage(driver);
    destinyClick.getClickOnHotelTab().click();
    //destinyClick.getDestinyClick1();
    //destinyClick.getDestinyClick2().sendKeys("cancun");
    //destinyClick.getDestinyClick2().click();
}
```

**This is the output:**

```
Scenario: Search Hotel With Travel Insurance             # SearchHotelWithTravelInsurance.feature:3
Given The browser is initialized                       # 
SearchAirTicketsStep.the_browser_is_initialized()
When User go to "https://www.turismocity.com.br/" site # SearchAirTicketsStep.user_go_to_site(String)
And Choose destiny or hotel name                       # 
SearchHotelStep.choose_destiny_or_hotel_name()
java.lang.NullPointerException
at pages.SearchHotelPage.getClickOnHotelTab(SearchHotelPage.java:28)
at steps.SearchHotelStep.choose_destiny_or_hotel_name(SearchHotelStep.java:22)
at ?.And Choose destiny or hotel name(SearchHotelWithTravelInsurance.feature:6)

And Choose round trip date                             # 
SearchAirTicketsStep.choose_round_trip_date()
And Choose quantity of guests                          # SearchHotelStep.choose_quantity_of_guests()
When Click on search button from hotels search         # 
SearchHotelStep.click_on_search_button_from_hotels_search()
Then The options of hotel are shown                    # 
SearchHotelStep.the_options_of_hotel_are_shown()
Then The page of travel insurance is open              # 
SearchHotelStep.the_page_of_travel_insurance_is_open()
Then The browser is closed                             # SearchAirTicketsStep.the_browser_is_closed()

Failed scenarios:
SearchHotelWithTravelInsurance.feature:3 # Scenario: Search Hotel With Travel Insurance

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
9 Steps (1 failed, 6 skipped, 2 passed)
0m9,057s

java.lang.NullPointerException
at pages.SearchHotelPage.getClickOnHotelTab(SearchHotelPage.java:28)
at steps.SearchHotelStep.choose_destiny_or_hotel_name(SearchHotelStep.java:22)
at ?.And Choose destiny or hotel name(SearchHotelWithTravelInsurance.feature:6)
```

**Can you help me, please ?**

Comment: Alex Rudenko, thanks for your help, but a I could solve the problem with the comment from another member. Thanks, guy !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure how selenium works, but it looks like the `WebDriver driver` variable is never assigned or created in your SearchHotelStep class, so it will always create a null pointer error.

You need to create or assign the driver before you use it.

For example `driver = yourCreatedDriver;` or `public WebDriver driver = new WebDriver(...);`

Something like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class SearchHotelStep extends BasePage {

public WebDriver driver = new WebDriver(...);

@When("^Choose destiny or hotel name$")
public void choose_destiny_or_hotel_name() throws Throwable {
    
    SearchHotelPage destinyClick = new SearchHotelPage(driver);
    destinyClick.getClickOnHotelTab().click();
}
```

Comment: Sorified, thanks a lot !!! It's was not exactly like you wrote above, but your idea is completely correct, it helped me. I'm so grateful !!!